# Multiple conditions in a Python if statement

Tags: python

```
i = 200

j = 201

if i == 200 | j == 201:
    print "Hi"
else:
    print "No"
```

It should print "Hi", right? So why it is printing "No"?

Comment: Note that `if (i == 200) | (j == 201):` would do what you expect...

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is actually one of **operator precedence**, not specifically of using a bitwise `|` rather than the logical `or`; `True | True` and `True or True` give the same result.

Per the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) the comparison `==` has lower precedence than bitwise `|`, so your conditional expression is evaluating to:

```
i == (200 | j) == 201
```

which is false. If you added parentheses to clarify:

```
(i == 200) | (j == 201)
```

you would get the behaviour you expected.

---

However, the correct thing to do is use `or`. Using `or` works because without parentheses because the boolean operators have lower precedence than comparisons. Additionally:

- it is more readable, as it is natural language to express what you mean
- it short circuits, so if the left-hand side is truthy the right-hand side doesn't need to be evaluated
- it works in a wider range of scenarios, where a bitwise operation would be a `TypeError`

Comment: In a scripting language one should also consider the handling of `None`. `True or None` does not throw an exception, `(True | None)` throws `TypeError`. `True and None` equals `None` but will act the same as `False` in an `if` statement.

Comment: Consider also function evaluations. Python `and` and `or` use short-circuit logic so `f() or g()` calls `f` but does not call `g` if `f` returns True or "truthy". `g() or f()` calls `g` but not `f` when `g` returns true. `( f() | g())` will always call both `f` and `g`. This gets to be very important when `f` or `g` are methods of class-instances which affect the instance's state when invoked.

Comment: @nigel222 yes, it's definitely correct to use `or`, but that's not why the OP's code didn't work as expected. I will make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `|` and `&` are bitwise operators, they do bit calculations.

On the other hand `and` and `or` are logical (boolean) operators.

Answer (score 1):

| is a bitwise operators and in python script do bit calculations
Use this

```
i = 200

j = 201

if i == 200 or j == 201:
    print "Hi"
else:
    print "No"
```